# C++: how to read **argv value and copy into a string

Tags: c++, string

I'm making a new app for my lab and  I must take form terminal some arguments, and I want to copy the `**args` value into a string, and after that I must match the `args` for execute some foreplay operation.

I try to build this code to copy the `**argv` value into string var but this is the error:

```
No source available for "std::string::operator=() at 0x44c1dc"
```

The code is this:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     string args[argc-1];
 int j=0;
 for(int i=2; i<argc-1;i++)
 {
    j=0;
    while(argv[i][j]!='\0')
    {
        args[i]=args[i]+argv[i][j];
        j++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since each entry in `argv` is a string, it's enough with a loop that does `args[i] = argv[i + 1]`

Answer (score 8):

I would propose this solution:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
std::copy(argv + 1, argv + argc, std::back_inserter(args));
```

References:

- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

---

To explain it a little, this copies from `argv[1]` (I don't care about `argv[0]` as it's the "command" and usually irrelevant for argument handling) into the vector. We stop copying at `argv[argc]` which is one beyond the end of the actual arguments (which is how "end" iterators work).

`std::back_inserter` creates a special iterator that is used to insert ad the end of containers.

Comment: Guess this is most likely the most compact solution, although a bit tricky for a newbie to understand - you might want to outline what's happening, rather than just linking to documentation.

Comment: +1, for showing off and for submitting a correct answer *first time*. (See edit history on my answer)

Comment: Why not just use the `begin, end` constructor of vector? (4 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector))

Answer (score 7):

Fastest and shortest solution with range constructor:

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argv + 1,argv + argc);
```

Comment: Not really range "insert"; it's just a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Make things as clear as you can. (Will help those 3am debugging sessions in your laboratory).

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     std::vector<std::string> args(argc);     
     for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
         args[i] = argv[i];
     }

    // rest of code here.    
}
```

Yes I know I waste `args[0]`, but do you really care about that? The indexing is so much clearer if you do it this way, `args` has the same indexing **conventions** as `argv` (which all us old cats are used to), and you don't get a whole lot of edge cases when you only pass the program name.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code, which also causes the odd problems. Also you're overcomplicating things quite a bit.

Here's what I'd do, this will require one additional header, `<vector>`, for the STL container, but it will make things a lot easier (since you shouldn't rely on being able to create arrays with dynamic lengths (also note that your array length might be 0, if there are no arguments given!))

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<const std::string>> params; // This is the container that will take all arguments.

    // Iterate over all arguments provided
    //  (skipping the very first, since that's the executable itself)
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        // Add the argument to the vector
        //  (this will construct a new std::string and add it to the end).
        params.push_back(argv[i]);

    // You're now able to access the arguments passed:
    // params.size() will return the number of arguments.
    // params[i] will return the i-th argument, starting at 0.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     string args[argc];
     int j=0;
     for(int i=2; i<argc;i++)
     {
         args[i-2].assign(argv[i]);

     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if I don't pass any argument to the program, i.e. `argc` is 1? :)

Comment: With the new edit you're skipping the first argument given (`argv[1]`, plus your array is still one entry too long. (Not trying to nag, just pointing out the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

first, you can't use a dynamic argument in a static expression. 
you must use either new to create a string array, or, better yet, use a vector (or any other container you like).
second, there is no point in copying the values one character by another. copy the entire string.

here is a sample code that will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<string> svec;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    svec strings;
    if(argc>1)
    {
        cout <<"arguments:"<<endl;

        for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
        {
            strings.push_back(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    for(auto i:strings)
    {
        cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

D.

Comment: *First, you can't use a dynamic argument in a static expression.* Some compilers will allow it, but you can't rely on it and you might run into problems (i.e. resulting length is 0).